# Output to CSV in postgres with double-quotes

Tags: postgresql, csv

Trying to dump the output of a query into a CSV file in an automated job and running into an issue with fields where the column contains my comma delimiter. With the nature of this particular network, I have to jump through a couple of hoops to get things done, and there's a good chance I'm missing something very obvious.

In a nutshell, I kick off my script from a client machine that uses PLINK to run a remote psql command on another box over an SSH connection. That psql command is hitting a Postgres server on a third machine (I can't connect directly from client to DB, hence the extra step in between).

If I manually SSH from client to server 1, connect to the Postgres box, and use \copy... with CSV header, the file that's created is perfect, and any fields that contain a comma are automatically surrounded by double quotes.

However, if I try go issue that \copy (or copy) command in a single command, the output doesn't contain those double quotes, so I end up in that situation where commas in a field are interpreted as a delimiter later one.

In other words, this has the necessary double-quotes:

1. SSH from client to server1.
2. psql -Uuser -h server2 database
3. \copy (select ...) to '~/myfile.csv' with CSV header;

But doesn't:

1. SSH from client to server1
2. `psql -Uuser -h server2 database -c "\copy (select ...) to '~/myfile.csv' with CSV header;"`

Comment: Did you try: `-c "\copy (select ...) to '~/myfile.csv' WITH (FORMAT CSV, HEADER TRUE, FORCE_QUOTE *);` ?

Comment: _I end up in that situation where commas in a field are interpreted as a delimiter later one_: that should not happen and if it does it's a bug that you could report. `force_quote` is not necessary for in-field separators or in-field double quotes to be quoted.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

## Using `FORCE_QUOTE`

Here is how to do:

```
psql -U user -h server2 database -c "\copy (select ...) to '~/myfile.csv' WITH (FORMAT CSV, HEADER TRUE, FORCE_QUOTE *);"
```

`COPY` command [documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-copy.html)

Comment: does this not work in redshift? I keep on getting an error at the file like "ERROR:  syntax error at or near "STDOUT"
LINE 1: COPY  DB.my_tab TO STDOUT WITH (FORMAT CSV,"

Answer (score 0):

Below command worked for me.

\copy (select * from table) TO 'filename.csv' WITH CSV HEADER FORCE QUOTE *;