# Export a PSQL table in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, database, psql

I have a languages tables in psql that look like this.

[image]

---

My goal is to export my `languages` table and import that back in using PHP.

## I've tried

**PHP**

Export

```
shell_exec('psql -E -U postgres -d portal -c "COPY languages TO \'/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/code/site/portal/public/csv/languages.csv\' DELIMITER \',\' "');
```

I got my `languages.csv` to export successfully.

If I open it up, it contain this.

```
1,h,Advanced Settings,Geavanceerde instellingen,Ajustes avanzados,Réglages avancés,2016-11-23 14:41:25,2016-11-23 14:41:25
```

---

My goal is get my `.csv` to exactly in this format

```
1,'h','Advanced Settings','Geavanceerde instellingen','Ajustes avanzados','Réglages avancés','2016-11-23 14:41:25','2016-11-23 14:41:25'
```

Because it is the **only** format that will **accept** by `psql`.

---

## Question

How do I adjust my psql command to get that ?

OR

Updating it using PHP is my only option ?

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22090820/4982088) maybe?

Comment: @Xorifelse : Thanks. I think that getting me very close without having to use PHP to modify those csv manually.

Comment: You saved my life mate :D !!!

Comment: Gosh, you make it sound that using PHP is aweful ;-)

Comment: No, I love PHP :) But I just don't want to take an extra steps - just to get the corrected format that will work with `psql` database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like the `FORCE_QUOTE` option on `COPY` can take a list of columns to wrap. See here: [SQL COPY](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/sql-copy.html)

`FORCE_QUOTE { ( column_name [, ...] ) | * }`

This means you can specify or it does all by default, you probably want the specify given your `id` column is not quote wrapped in your example.