# Quote strings and dates in psql query results output

Tags: postgresql, psql, postgresql-11

Under the section [\pset [ option [ value ] ]](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/app-psql.html) of the `psql` docs, I can set various settings to make my query results convenient for me.

I can, for example, approach a CSV-like output with:

```
\pset fieldsep ','
\pset footer off
\pset format unaligned
\pset null 'NULL'
```

Resulting in output like:

```sql
> WITH foo_tbl(foo,bar,baz)
> AS
> (
>   VALUES
>   ('foo', NULL, 1),
>   (NULL, 'bar', 1)
> )
> SELECT * FROM foo_tbl;
foo,bar,baz
foo,NULL,1
NULL,bar,1
```

This is great, but I'd like strings and dates to be quoted, like this:

```yaml
foo,bar,baz
'foo',NULL,1
NULL,'bar',1
```

Is this not possible with psql?

p.s. I know this kind of thing can be done with SQL clients like DBeaver, but that isn't in the scope of this question.

Comment: Loot at this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22078456/output-to-csv-in-postgres-with-double-quotes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To generate CSV output, you can use the [`copy` command](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-copy.html) rather than trying to tweak the output of a regular SELECT statement.

```
copy (
  WITH foo_tbl (foo,bar,baz,dt) AS
  (
    VALUES
      ('foo', NULL, 1, date '2020-01-02'),
      (NULL, 'bar', 1, date '2020-03-04')
  )
  SELECT * 
  FROM foo_tbl
) to stdout 
  with (format csv, quote '''', header, null 'NULL', force_quote (foo, dt) );
```

Will generate the following output

```
foo,bar,baz,dt           
'foo',NULL,1,'2020-01-02'
NULL,bar,1,'2020-03-04'
```

I am not aware of an option that will quote only dates and strings, but not numbers, so using `force_quote` and specifying the columns to quote is the only way to get them (always).

`copy (...) to stdout` is easier to use than it's `psql` sibling `\copy` because it allows multi-line queries.

To write everything into a file, you can use the `\o` command in psql

```
postgres=> \o data.csv
postgres=> copy (...) to stdout with (...);
```

Comment: Shame about having to use `force_quote` isn't it? Seems like a fairly common use case to quote character and date fields and no others. Regardless, this is clearly the right way to do this +1.